# Need Help to Visualize Atom contact in Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, cgal, meshlab

I am new to CGAL . I am working on a school project to compute the Delaunay Triangulation of Protein structure . How can I visualize the DT structure in Mesh lab . I tried using Poison surface reconstruction, but PSR is using constrained DT and adding new edges which is not I want.

I want to visualize the edge contacts between 3d atom points in Delaunay 
Triangulation. Could anyone help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to visualize exactly? The basic thing you could extract from a Delaunay Triangulation would be pairs of atoms (that might not be in contact depending on the length of the Delaunay edge connecting them).

Comment: Basically I want to visualize the whole DT . Do I need to use PSR to extract it to .OFF format to view in MeshLab or Is there any other way to do it .

Answer (score 0):

Poisson surface reconstruction is not using constrained Delaunay Triangulation, it is defining a function which 0-level is meshed using the CGAL surface mesher.
If you want to compute the Delaunay triangulation of a point set, simply use the class [`Delaunay_triangulation_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__3.html). The best way to visualize the triangulation is to display its edges. I don't think meshlab is able to display polylines but I think it is pretty straight forward to modify one of the example provided by CGAL, extract the edges of the triangulation and generate for example a CGO that you can open in PyMol in addition to your protein structure.

Comment: Thank you . I used an example code from  "CGAL Advancing Front Surface Reconstruction" which I believe uses 3D Delaunay Triangulation and I was able to view the Protein Triangulation structure in MeshLab . It would be helpful If you could tell me What is CGO and How can I use it with Delaunay_triangulation_3 class to visualize . Is there some way to extract ?